# Django Many To Many Relationship "through"

Tags: python, django

I'm building a model of an equipment which have multiple pieces. Each piece is a model and there is a ManyToMany relationship between them.

```
class Station(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField

class Sensor(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField
    brand = models.CharField
    model = models.CharField
    station = models.ManyToManyField(Station, through='Relationship')

class Digitalizer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField
    brand = models.CharField
    model = models.CharField
    station = models.ManyToManyField(Station, through='Relationship2')

class Relationship(models.Model):

    station = models.ForeignKey(Station)
    sensor = models.ForeignKey(Sensor)
    setting_up_date = models.DateField()
    removal_date = models.DateField()
```

As I want to save some historic info about the pieces that are included on the equipment I want to use an intermediary model or relationship to save the info about the dates the pieces were installed and removed (similar to the membership example of the doc https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/)

My question is, can I use the same "relationship" for 2 or more models that i need to be associated with Sensor Model?  Or do i need to replicate the relationship for every model?

Something like this

```
class Relationship(models.Model):

    station = models.ForeignKey(Station)

    sensor = models.ForeignKey(Sensor)
    digitalizer = models.ForeignKey(Digitalizer)
    foo = models.ForeignKey(Foo)
    setting_up_date = models.DateField()
    removal_date = models.DateField()
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused by your question, but I'd place the dates (removal etc) directly inside the related model (i.e removed piece), and link them (pieces) to both the station (?) and history model, but only removing it from the station when the removal takes place.

Comment: First, your intermediate model should contain only one foreign key to source model, and only one foreign key to target model.  You will def get an error if you add "foo=models.ForeignKey(Foo)". Behind the scene, thats just how SQL is designed to handle M2M fields.
Second, to answer your question if I understand it correctly, you CAN'T use the same relationship intermediate model because the source and target model are different, but you could use another intermediate model like you have already used "relationship2" with same schema as relationship model.